# Make COM-version of VB.NET UserControl available in 64-bit edition of Microsoft Office

Tags: vb.net, com, 64-bit, ms-office, winforms-interop

We have a VB.NET project that wraps a WinForms control with the .NET UserControl and makes it available as a COM assembly for use in Microsoft Office. The project uses the standard technique for doing this, i.e. we set the 'Make Assembly COM-Visible' and 'Register for COM Interop’ checkboxes in the project properties, sign the assembly with a strong name, etc. The essential code related to the component registration in the registry is the following:

```vb
<ComRegisterFunction()>
Public Shared Sub RegisterForCOM(ByVal aType As Type)
    Dim strCtrlKey, strVersion As String
    Dim typeLibGUID As Guid
    strCtrlKey = "CLSID\" + aType.GUID.ToString("B")
    Dim key As RegistryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(strCtrlKey, True)
    key.CreateSubKey("Control")
    key.CreateSubKey("Implemented Categories\{40FC6ED4-2438-11CF-A3D8-080036F12502}")
    key.CreateSubKey("MiscStatus").SetValue("", "131457")
    typeLibGUID = Marshal.GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly(aType.Assembly)
    key.CreateSubKey("TypeLib").SetValue("", typeLibGUID.ToString("B"))
    Dim asmVersion As Version = aType.Assembly.GetName().Version
    strVersion = asmVersion.Major.ToString() + "." + asmVersion.Minor.ToString()
    key.CreateSubKey("Version").SetValue("", strVersion)
    key.Close()
End Sub

<ComUnregisterFunction()>
Public Shared Sub UnregisterForCOM(ByVal aType As Type)
    Try
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKeyTree("CLSID\" + aType.GUID.ToString("B"))
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

This construction has worked without any problems for years until the moment when our customers tried to use this .NET COM wrapper in a 64-bit edition of Microsoft Office. I tried to find an answer to this question in the Internet, but I could not find a guide how to implement a 64-bit compatible COM wrapper for a WinForms control.

Is it possible at all? If so, can you point us in the right direction?

---

UPDATE: Currently our users use the following command in the command prompt launched with the admin rights to register the COM wrapper:

```
regasm <full_path_to_dll> /tlb /codebase
```

Comment: This is not a problem, but critical info is missing in the question.  Your users are not clicking the "'Register for COM Interop" checkbox.  You have to explain how this component is registered on the user's machine.  If you created an installer for it then it must be a 64-bit installer.  If they use Regasm.exe then they must use the 64-bit version of it.

Comment: @HansPassant, our users do use regasm. I have just added this command line call to the question.

Comment: I suppose your users are savvy enough to figure it out from the incomplete install instruction, but that they don't know which of the four versions of Regasm.exe to use is unsurprising.  Why don't you just try it yourself and you'll quickly see what is wrong with it.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you for your hint regarding different versions of regasm for different architectures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HansPassant for helping to find the answer. To register the .NET COM wrapper for the 64-bit Office, our customers needed to launch the corresponding regasm from the Framework64 subfolder. The full command line looks like this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm <full_path_to_dll> /tlb /codebase
```